# arcpy.AddJoin_management() results not writing to file in ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, attribute-joins, arcgis-10.4

This is probably just me struggling with some of the ArcGIS concepts, but I can't get the results of an AddJoin_management call to write to the layer where I've made the join.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('C:\\My Documents\\ArcGISmaps\\blank template.mxd')
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

## Take geography from 'Resource library.mdb'
mapSource = os.path.join('C:\\My Documents\\ArcGISmaps\\Resource library.mdb', 'regions')

#Specify data frame & layer
bLyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(mapSource)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, bLyr, 'AUTO_ARRANGE')

imdSource = 'C:\\My Documents\\ArcGISmaps\\IMD_02.dbf'

imdTable = arcpy.mapping.TableView(imdSource)
arcpy.mapping.AddTableView(df, imdTable)

try:
    arcpy.AddJoin_management(bLyr, "Reg_ID", imdTable, "ID", 'KEEP_ALL')
except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
mxd.save()
```

When I open the file in ArcMap 10.4, the tables have been successfully added to the TOC, but there's no evidence of the join being included. If I include `getMessages()` in the `try:` block, it suggests the join has been successful.

What do I need to do to write the join onto `bLyr`?

---

A combination of SaveToLayerFile_management and reimporting the joined table as a new layer has done the trick so I now have:

```
arcpy.AddJoin_management(bLyr, "ONSCD", imdTable, "MSOACD", 'KEEP_ALL')
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(bLyr, "C:\\My Documents\\ArcGISmaps\\postJoin.lyr", "ABSOLUTE") 

postJoin = arcpy.mapping.Layer("C:\\My Documents\\ArcGISmaps\\postJoin.lyr")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, postJoin, "AUTO_ARRANGE")
```

Comment: I think it's the sequence on how you get a handle on the layers and tables. You create them from their source path then add them to the mxd. You do not get them *from* the mxd and create the join. Try creating them, adding them, saving the mxd then getting them *from* the mxd, build the join then save the mxd.

Comment: I think it is always best to remove any `try`/`except` statements from [code snippets](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers) that you present here.

Comment: Is that the convention round here, to omit any `try/except`? I'll bear that in mind for future questions!

Comment: It can often mask errors that would otherwise point at the cause of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is explained in the [Add Join help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-join.htm) where it says:

> - The join lasts only for the duration of the session. To persist the join for use in another session, save the layer to a layer file using
>     the Save Layer To File tool. This only applies to layers; table views
>     cannot be saved in this manner.