# AddJoin_management does not appear to work?

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins, python-script-tool

I've taken the code snippet below from a larger block of code in order test it and made a script tool with it in ArcMap:

```py
import arcpy
#Set join parameter variables
inFeatures = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
inField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
joinTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
joinField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inFeatures,"inFeatures_lyr") #make feature layer from feature class
#Join road feature class to buffer distance table
arcpy.AddJoin_management("inFeatures_lyr", inField, joinTable, joinField, "KEEP_ALL")
```

In setting up the script tool, I've defined the variable `inFeatures` as a feature class, `inField` as a field, `joinTable` as a table, and `joinField` as a field.  When I run the tool no errors are generated but no join is created.

Is there a problem with this code snippet?

Is the `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management` unnecessary or causing problems?

Comment: Have you tested the join tool outside your script using the tables to prove a valid join is indeed created? Also looking at your code I see no immediate problem which suggests the join is created, without seeing the rest of the code it's hard to suggest anything as we don't know if you run a remove join later in the code?

Comment: There is a remove join in the larger code but it's commented out because I haven't been able to do a successful join.  I ran the `AddJoin_management` as a stand-alone in the python window in ArcMap and it worked there.

Comment: @SDRobinson As per your other questions, please include the actual values instead of `arcpy.GetParameterAsText`.  Have you tested it with hard-coded values?  What was the result?

Comment: I seem to get the same outcome using hard-coded values in PythonWin; it appears to run but there's no values joined to the feature class.  I have to use `MakeFeatureLayer_management` on the input feature class, else I get an error.

Comment: I can run the script with hard-coded values in the ArcMap Python window and it runs correctly.

Comment: `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)` is the input feature **class**.  `arcpy.GetParametersAsText(1)` is the join field in the feature class. `arcpy.GetParametersAsText(2)` is the table to join.  `arcpy.GetparametersAsText(3)` is the join field in the table.  These would all be input in the script tool in ArcMap.

Comment: You say "I seem to get the same outcome using hard-coded values in PythonWin" but until we see those hardcoded values or some `arcpy.AddMessage()` of the values captured by your `arcpy.GetParameterAsText()` statements there is little incentive to try and test because we may be using different data types.

Comment: Also you say "no join is created" but you don't demonstrate that to be the case in your code snippet or explain how you come to that conclusion.  Its only a hunch but I wonder whether this may be a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243393